# Is knowledge of someone owning a firearm enough for police action/prosecution?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, england-and-wales, firearms

Bob and Eve are work colleagues. Eve owns an unlicensed firearm, which could be illegal, be that a pistol, rifle or a shotgun. Eve mentions that she owns such a weapon to Bob. Bob is concerned for his safety and wants to do some sort of action.

Can the police take action against Eve based on Bob’s knowledge alone?

Would Eve be prosecuted or only have her firearm seized?

Comment: Im voting to close this because I fear it cannot be answered in any authoritive manner. Police are a law upon themselves.

Comment: @NeilMeyer: Personal, my tendency is to interpret questions of the form, "Can [X] do [Y]?" as, "Can [X] do [Y] legally?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

Most police investigations start with a report of suspicion of illegal activity from the public.

Whether a particular report gets acted on and what action the police will take is up to them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which boils down to whether the specific kind of report would _normally_ trigger the police to act. It is not so much about what the law requires the police to do but rather what their usual practices are in regards to handling reports like this.

Comment: @Greendrake in that case, the question would be out of scope of Law.SE

Comment: @Trish Practices of _law enforcement_ out of scope here? Come on.

Comment: @Greendrake the police generally do whatever they like. It is not really easy to determine what police are likely to do.

Comment: @NeilMeyer More importantly, there are very few legal boundaries governing what police do. There is no authoritative answer. The law answers what the government could do (it could prosecute, it could seize the weapon, it could question the suspect, it could get a warrant to search for it).